# Как получить даты по порядку в рамках одной недели?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Помогите решить такую задачу:

у меня есть функция которая возвращает начало и конец недели в зависимости от сегодняшнего дня. К примеру:

**Сегодня суббота, 30 сентября**. Функция берет эту дату и возвращает дату начала недели:

```
2017-09-25
```

и вторую дату - конец недели:

```
2017-10-01
```

Мне необходимо получить массив, который будет начинаться с первой даты и заканчивать второй, но между ними будут идти даты по порядку.

Вот такой массив должен получиться:

```
"2017-09-25", "2017-09-26", "2017-09-27", "2017-09-28", "2017-09-29", "2017-09-30", "2017-10-01"
```

Помогите пожалуйста готовым кодом на php. Мне необходимо также учитывать переход между годами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать **[DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateperiod.php)**, который представляет временной период и позволяет перемещаться в заданном временном интервале на равные промежутки времени.

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime('2017-09-25'),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     (new DateTime('2017-10-01'))->modify('+1 day') // +1 day нужен так как конец не входит в интервал
);

$result = [];
foreach( $period as $date) { 
    $result[] = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
} 

//-------------------------------------------
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Выведет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-09-25
    [1] => 2017-09-26
    [2] => 2017-09-27
    [3] => 2017-09-28
    [4] => 2017-09-29
    [5] => 2017-09-30
    [6] => 2017-10-01
)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант:

```
$start = strtotime('2017-09-25');
$stop = strtotime('2017-10-01');
$all_days = ($stop - $start) / (3600 * 24);
$dates = [];

for ($i = 0; $i <= $all_days; $i++) {
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', $start + (3600 * 24 * $i));
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($dates); echo '</pre>';
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-09-25
    [1] => 2017-09-26
    [2] => 2017-09-27
    [3] => 2017-09-28
    [4] => 2017-09-29
    [5] => 2017-09-30
    [6] => 2017-10-01
)
*/
```